# How to see if a Django QueryDict key matches a pattern

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on a site with a list-type view (shopping cart) where each item has a select drop-down widget to change shipping type. The resulting HTML, created by a for loop such that 'item_id_foo' changes on each cycle, looks like:

```
<select name='item_id_foo'>
<option value='bar1'>bar1</option>
...
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Change'/>
</select>
```

As a result, by request.POST.copy has a key/value like {'item_id_foo':'bar1'}. My question is how to find keys that look like 'item_id_foo', 'item_id_bar', etc. Methods like "getitem", "get" or "contains" assume you know what the full key looks like, and I only know the pattern. How do I match for a pattern on a key?

Thank you,
bkev

Update: Example values for the select would be like:
'item_id_1', 'item_id_2', 'item_id_3'...matching the id of the item in the cart that needs to be edited (each has its own shipping method and fee).

Comment: Could you add a few more sample values? When you say - "keys that look like 'item_id_foo'", isn't that the whole key of the dict you listed?

Comment: Why wouldn't you calculate the key in the same way your shopping cart creates the select input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not loop through the entire list and then do regex on each item's name? `QueryDict.lists()` or `QueryDict.values()` allows you to get all of it and then loop through that.

**QueryDict.lists()**
Like items(), except it includes all values, as a list, for each member of the dictionary.

For example:

```
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&a=3')
>>> q.lists()
[(u'a', [u'1', u'2', u'3'])]
```

Link: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the keys and keep those you want

```
>>> post = {'item_id_1': 1, 'item_id_2': 2, 'item_id_3': 3, 'noitem': 0}
>>> dict([(k, v) for k, v in post.items() if k[:8] == 'item_id_'])
{'item_id_3': 3, 'item_id_2': 2, 'item_id_1': 1}
```